# python 2.7 - encode os in utf8

Tags: python-2.7, character-encoding

I am using python 2.7.11
and my program run a command line which push info to database,that shuld be in utf8

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
cmd = "push.exe -c set_value chữQuốcngữ"
os.system(cmd)
```

in python 3.6 it works perfect.
However,my environment has only python 2.7.11, and the data in database look like that : chá»¯Quá»‘cngá»¯

I suspect os.system opens a command prompt and thats the reason, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Try using the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module instead of `os.system`.

Comment: I tried,also didn't work

Comment: Even if you use unicode strings? `Popen([u'push.exe', u'-c', u'set_value', u'chữQuốcngữ'])`?

Comment: doing it, i am getting UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u1eef' in position 73: ordinal not in range(128)